# LINQ to XML: applying an XPath

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

Can someone tell me why this program doesn't enumerate any items? Does it have something to do with the RDF namespace?

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("http://seattle.craigslist.org/sof/index.rss");

        foreach (var item in doc.XPathSelectElements("//item"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Element("link").Value);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely about the namespace - although it's the RSS namespace, not the RDF one. You're trying to find items without a namespace.

Using a namespace in XPath in .NET is slightly tricky, but in this case I'd just use the LINQ to XML `Descendants` method instead:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("http://seattle.craigslist.org/sof/index.rss");
        XNamespace rss = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/";

        foreach (var item in doc.Descendants(rss + "item"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Element(rss + "link").Value);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Winner winner, chicken dinner.

Comment: A complete example of parsing RDF, RSS and ATOM in C# can be found here http://www.jarloo.com/rumormill-5/ also full source code available.