# MVC2 - Consume RSS feed with RDF and namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, rss, rdf

I' trying to read the feed for the Washington Departmene of Fish and Wildlife, and keep etting this error:

> The element with name 'RDF' and
>   namespace
>   'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'
>   is not an allowed feed format.

Here's the code from RssController:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    string feedUrl = @"http://wdfw.wa.gov/news/newsrss.php";

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(feedUrl))
    {

        **SyndicationFeed rss = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);**

        return View(rss);
    }            
}
```

I've done seveal RSS applications but nave never ran into this issue. Anyone got any concrete ways of being able to parse this in ASP.NET MVC 2? (the lines with asterics are where the exception happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no support for RSS 1.0. Example of how to roll your own support here : https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140320/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031809-1.aspx

Comment: That 4guys link is broken at the moment (compile error on the page, and source code visible!). I realise it's 4 years later, but I found myself needing to parse an RSS 1.0 feed today, so here's another approach from The Skeet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583086/linq-to-xml-applying-an-xpath

Answer (score 2):

This may not be applicable to you as it sounds like you are only interested in RSS, but if you want RDF support for your application (RSS 1.0 uses RDF/XML to encode it's data) then you could try my library [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org).

I suspect that a full blown RDF API is probably overkill though judging from your question.

Comment: RobV I downloaded your RDF API __in case__ I cant get this other solution working. Nice work by the way