# Consuming RSS 1.0 (RDF) Feeds in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rss

Can anyone know how to consume RSS 1.0 in ASP.NET MVC3?

Answer (score 2):

I would just use this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(“URL to RSS Feed”);
```

And then you can query using Linq to XML like this...

```
var query = from feed in doc.Descendants(“item”)
orderby DateTime.Parse(feed.Element(“pubDate”).Value) descending
select new
{
   Title = feed.Element(“title”).Value,
   Description = feed.Element(“description”).Value,
   Date = DateTime.Parse(feed.Element(“pubDate”).Value)
};
```

Comment: Thank JTWebMan, you code is work. But it cannot get any elements if RSS have RDF namespace. I just find solution from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583086/linq-to-xml-applying-an-xpath