# Consuming RSS Feeds in VB ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, rss

The only article I could find on this was [Consuming RSS 1.0 (RDF) Feeds in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227031/consuming-rss-1-0-rdf-feeds-in-asp-net-mvc-3).  It uses LINQ.  Is there anyway to do it using a lambda expression?  Is there any better way to consume and RSS feed in MVC3?

Here is my code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description
Imports System.ServiceModel.Syndication
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class RssController

    Function GetFeed(url As String) As SyndicationFeed

        Dim reader = XmlReader.Create(url)
        Dim feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader)
        Return feed

    End Function

    Function ShowFeed() As ViewResult

        Dim feedUrl = "somefeedurl"
        Dim feed = GetFeed(feedUrl)
        Return View(feed)

    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET has a builtin class for handling RSS feeds called [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx)

You can use this class as an alternative for writing your own parsing logic.

Comment: That article seems to show how to create but not consume.  Can you post an example of RSS consumption?  I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369794/good-and-full-implementation-of-rss-feeds-in-asp-net-mvc?rq=1 but was looking for more info.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412174.aspx has a full example of providing and consuming a RSS-feed using the SyndicationFeed

Comment: How do I output the feed?  It says, "View is a type and cannot be used as an expression" on the line Return View(feed).  Please let me know if you're not sure so I can promptly ask a new question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MVC in VB. you may need to extract the data from the SyndicationFeed Items collection and transform it to a Model, but I think if you use IEmumerable of SyndicationItem as the model in your HTML view that should work